# In Flux what's the appropriate way for an action in one React component to affect another component?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to wrap my head around Facebook's Flux...

Say I have an app with a side menu that can be hidden and shown via a button in the header.

My header is one component, my side menu is another component.

Currently my Header component just sets a class on the HTML div side menu element which gets animated to hidden by CSS.

What's the general idea here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactJs doesn't really care about how it gets its data (how it's data is getting passed in or how that data should be handled across the web application). That's where Flux comes in, it creates a functional approach on how data is handled. Data-flow is essentially:

```
Action -> Data Store -> Component
```

Mutation of data happen through calling Actions. The Data Stores themselves have to listen on the actions and mutate the data within the store. This keeps the data structure and logic flat.

In your case, your dataflow would probably look something like this:

Header --> User Click --> Fires action --> Updates store --> Side menu listening and responding to that store change.

Your case is a simple example which you probably don't really need Flux. I think it's easier if you have a parent component that maintains the view state logic, and use props/callbacks for the 2 children components (side menu and header). But a more advanced example that you need to make ajax calls and maintain session, Flux would become useful. Like if you have a Login Component, and you want to show different side-menu options and header options depending on user:

```
Login Component --> User Logins --> Calls Action #signIn --> Showing Loading State
                                                         --> Dispatcher handles action (make api call to authenticate user and load user data)

On success (for the api call), alert sessionStore, and populate store with data
On error, maybe fire another action that says login failed or something

SessionStore ---> Header Component (Listens to Store) --> Update view based on store information
             ---> Side Menu Component (Listens to Store) --> Update
```

Comment: This is one of the situations where flux or an event emitter is useful.  The toggle button and sidebar aren't really related to the header component.  The toggle button could easily be in the footer, or elsewhere, or in multiple places, or not exist at all.  This makes passing a handler to the header non-sensible, as you'd logically have to pass this handler to other possible components it could be rendered into (or else the caller of header has to know its implementation, which is bad).

Comment: _Side Menu Component --> User Click --> Fire action #buttonClick --> Store listens and respond to that action, change the state --> Header Component listens to Store changes, and responds when the store has changed_  I assume you swapped Side Menu Component and Header Component here?  The button is in the header and triggers the side menu to hide.

Comment: oh whoops, yeah my bad. It would be Header --> User Click --> Fires action --> Updates store --> Side menu listening and responding to that store change

Answer (score 0):

speaking more general:

flux is a software architecture for a unidirectional Dataflow. It's Chain is Action -> Delegation -> Store -> View... The action - for example a Button Click - gets delegated to stores where your applicationlogic and data is kept... here your action and data will be changed and processed. The store eventually emits an event which views (for example react components) previously registered on with a callback. In this callback you can GET your data from your stores. It is important to mention that you can only access the stores READ-Only.

So for your case... if you want component A to affect component B you will have to register component B to the store eventEmitter and GET the desired data from the store. Once component a triggers an action it gets delegated to the store, your functions are performed and eventually the event gets thrown that starts component B's callback.

Hope this got clear enough... its way cooler with some nice drawings.